# End script and restart it with the same options and arguments

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bash-history

Usually !! repeats the last given command. But it doesn’t seem to work in a bash script. Is there a way to end a script and repeat it with the exact same options and arguments given the last time?

*Additional info*: In a part of my script it is checked if a server is running. If it isn't, it is started by etherwake. This is the part, where I want the script to be ended and restarted, until the server is finally up. Ignoring the problem that this easily can lead to a endless loop which might threaten system/network stability.

Is there an easier/safer way? There doesn't seem to be a GOTO LINE command or something similar.

Comment: I am not sure where in the process the options and arguments get in the picture?

Answer (score 2):

Just make an infinite while loop:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> while [ TRUE ]; do
>
> > check_server_status 10.0..
> >     etherwake ff:ff..
>
> done

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
while server-is-not-running; do
    try-and-start-server
    sleep seconds-to-wait
done
```

where

- `server-is-not-running` is your current test to see if the server is running, i.e. a shell function or an external command returning non-zero if the server is running (alternatively, `! server-is-running` if that function or command returns zero if the server *is* running).
- `try-and-start-server` is the command to start the server, which again can be a shell function or external command
- `seconds-to-wait` is a sensible number of seconds to wait for successful start

To limit the number of attempts, replace the `while` with a `for`:

```
for i in {1..number-of-attempts}; do
    try-and-start-server
    sleep seconds-to-wait
    server-is-not-running || break
done
```

Comment: I think this will do the trick quite elegantly. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear @Markus, however please adhere to Askubuntu policy: no Thanks! comments, instead mark the answer as such.